# Use of static data inside iostream header

Tags: c++, iostream

I was playing around on *godbolt.org*, and noticed some [*"extra code"*](https://godbolt.org/g/lCBXF8) added by compiler with an *'empty main()'* with `iostream` header included.

After looking into standards I figured those are needed to constructs and initializes the objects `cin`, `cout`, `cerr`, `clog`, `wcin`, `wcout`, `wcerr`, and `wclog,` if they have not already been constructed/initialized.

**N4606: § 27.5.3.1.6**

> ```
> 27.5.3.1.6 Class ios_base::Init [ios::Init] 
>
> namespace std {
>    class ios_base::Init {
>       public:
>          Init();
>          ~Init();
>       private:
>          static int init_cnt; // exposition only
>    };
> }
> ```

But for the `static` data all that standard says it counts the number of constructor and destructor calls for `class Init`, and is initialized to zero.

> 2 For the sake of exposition, the maintained data is presented here
>   as: (2.1) — static int init_cnt, counts the number of constructor and
>   destructor calls for class Init, initialized to zero.

What I don't get is what is the use of `static int init_cnt;` here ?
Why we need to counting how many times constructor/destructor is called ?

Comment: Looks like it is used to flush only on the last destruction(from cppreference): *The class tracks how many instances of it are created and initializes the C++ streams when the first instance is constructed as well as flushes the output streams when the last instance is destructed.*

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter explains some of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus/blob/master/ios.cpp#L163 I think that **if is needed** then program at the end when calling destructors for global variables can properly destruct cin, cout, cerr, clog, wcin, wcout, wcerr and wclog.

From http://www.csci.csusb.edu/dick/c++std/september/lib-iostreams.html :

> ~Init();
>
> Effects:
>       Destroys an object of class Init.  The function subtracts  one  from
>       the  value  stored in init_cnt and, if the resulting stored value is
>       one, calls cout.flush(), cerr.flush(), clog.flush(),  wcout.flush(),
>       wcerr.flush(), wclog.flush().